# Formik handleBlur use case

Tags: reactjs, formik

What are use cases for `handleBlur`? Since you can access touched fields through the `touched` object.

From Formik Docs:

`handleBlur: (e: any) => void`

`onBlur` event handler. Useful for when you need to track whether an input has been `touched` or not. This should be passed to `<input onBlur={handleBlur} ... />`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

handleBlur is how touched is actually updated (or at least one of the ways). If your input isn't passed an onBlur handler connecting to Formik's state, the touched state won't be updated.

Here is a codesandbox illustrating the behavior: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-gates-4cq5k?file=/src/App.js

If you blur the first input, touched is updated. If you blur the second input, touched is not updated. The third input uses `useField`, which results in an `onBlur` field being passed to my input automatically. This is typically how I like to work with Formik (or pretty much any other react form library), since it cuts down on the boilerplate necessary to connect form fields to the state of the form.

```
import React from "react";
import { Formik, Form, useField } from "formik";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ usingUseField: "", withBlur: "", withoutBlur: "" }}
      >
        {({ handleChange, handleBlur, values, touched }) => {
          return (
            <Form>
              {JSON.stringify(touched)}
              <div>
                <label>
                  With Blur
                  <input
                    onBlur={handleBlur("withBlur")}
                    onChange={handleChange("withBlur")}
                    value={values.withBlur}
                  />
                </label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label>
                  Without Blur
                  <input
                    onChange={handleChange("withoutBlur")}
                    value={values.withoutBlur}
                  />
                </label>
              </div>
              <InputUsingUseField name="usingUseField" label="Using useField" />
            </Form>
          );
        }}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
}

function InputUsingUseField({ label, name }) {
  const [props] = useField(name);

  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        {label}
        <input {...props} />
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}
```